# Download and merge files from BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to Git, so please, go easy on me.

I'm working on a project stored on BitBucket with another person. So whenever he makes any changes, how do I download them and merge any changed files into my project folder?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll have a look into it - thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You first need your colleague to share the repository with your username on bitbucket, once done you must first then clone the repository:

eg:

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repository.git
```

This will check out the code from bit bucket. If you've already done this much, you can enter the directory and instead type:

```
git pull
```

This will pull down all the latest changes to the bitbucket repository.

You really need to sit down some day and give this a read :) http://git-scm.com/book/

Hope it helps some.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Why does he have to use my username though?

Comment: That is simply an example of the path to the bitbucket.org git repository. Once you have shared the repository with your college, he can log into bitbucket and get the correct path to the repository which will include his username at the points shown in my answer :)